# Condicion When en Query Builder laravel : Call to a member function all() on null

Tags: laravel

estoy luchando con esta querie utilizando la funcion when y no logro hacerla funcionar.

```
   public function collection()
    {

         
        $turnos = DB::table('turnos as t') 
        ->select('t.profesional','t.dia','t.hora','t.paciente','o.descripcion as desc_osocial',
        'pa.plan','pa.nrosocial','tr.descripcion as tratamiento')
        ->join('pacientes as pa', 't.paciente','=','pa.id')
        ->join('obrasocials as o', 'pa.osocial','=','o.id')
        ->join('tratamientos as tr', 'tr.id','=','t.tratamiento')
        ->where('profesional', $_SESSION['excelprofe2'])
        ->where('dia','>=', $_SESSION['exceldesde'])
        ->where('dia','<=',$_SESSION['excelhasta'])
        ->whereNotnull('paciente')        
        ->when($_SESSION['exceltrata']==0,
        function($q) {
            return $q->where('tratamiento','=','tratamiento');
        },
        function($q) {
            return $q->where('tratamiento','=',$_SESSION['exceltrata']);
        });
        $turnos->get();      
    }
```

El error que me da es
Call to a member function all() on null

Aguardo como siempre la ayuda de todos.
Gracias.-

Comment: coloca el query completo, por lo que veo estas llamando el closure en un objeto vacio

Comment: Ahi la edite. Sin la parte de When, me funciona correcto la querie, por eso solo habia subido esa parte., Gracias-.

Comment: When es un metodo de eloquent no del query builder, te recomiendo mejor hacer la consulta con el orm y que reemplaces el when con un scope, el when es sumamente pesado ya que va preguntar la condicion en todos los registros

Comment: @JuanManuelFerrero ¿por qué mezclas dentro de la construcción de la query el uso de when?

Comment: la verdad es que encontré el uso del when buscando en google. no sabia que no era de query builder. agradezco la enseñanza voy a buscar si encuentro como utilizar el scope. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @NicolasAldana te equivocas, puede ser usado en ambos https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses. Aunque la documentacion solo muestre en Query Builder

Comment: @JuanManuelFerrero ve mi comentario, si se puede usar el `when` en ambos casos "Query Builder y Eloquent"

Comment: @JuanManuelFerrero por otro lado, en alguna parte de tu codigo haces un `->all()`?

Comment: Por ultimo, deberias leer mas la documentacion, ya que sigues usando `$_SESSION` de php en vez de [session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session) de laravel

Comment: y qué ventaja tiene el helper de laravel sobre la superglobal?

Comment: por qué tienes dos closure en el when?, en si que quieres lograr con la consulta?

Comment: Si en un select option me eligen --Todos-- envio a la consulta 0 sino envio el id que corresponda.  Eso quiero filtrar en el when.
Ahora lo solucione con un if al incio del querie segun el id ejecuta uno u otro querie. No es la solucion que queria pero para salir del paso me funciona.